# A stop job is running for Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio

Tags: pigpio, raspbian-buster

Since I installed Buster I have experienced slow shutdown.
A message is displayed:-

```
A stop job is running for Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
```

and persists for 90 seconds.

I have `pigpiod.service` enabled and running on all my Pi, although AFAIK there is nothing actually using it on my Pi4 at the moment.

This doesn't happen every time, but WHY and how can I stop it holding up poweroff?

Comment: I have the same issue - did you ever find a solution?